# async.parallel to async await - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, async.js

I am using express-promise-router to achieve async/await in my query calls from node.js. Sometimes, when I need to fetch data for tables, I use async.parallel to get the data as well as the count as separate data and merge them. I am using callbacks here. How do I go ahead using async/await for these?

```
router.post('/getDetail', (request, response, next) => {

  const id = request.body.id;
  const numPerPage = request.body.pSize;
  const pageNum = request.body.pIndex;

  let query = `select id,name,title,group_desc,unit_code from table1
              where id = '${id}'`;

  let countQuery = `select count(*) total_item from 
                   (select id,name,title,group_desc,unit_code from table1
                    where id = '${id}') a`;

  const result = {};

  async.parallel({
    rows: (cb) => {
      pool.query(
        query,
        (err, data) => {
          if (!err) {
            result.dataRows = data.rows;
            result.numPerPage = numPerPage;
            result.pageNum = pageNum;
            result.totalPage = Math.ceil(result.totalItem / numPerPage);
            result.firstItem = (pageNum - 1) * numPerPage + 1;
            result.lastItem = (pageNum * numPerPage > result.totalItem) ?
              result.totalItem : (pageNum * numPerPage)
          }
          cb(err, result)
        })
    },
    count: (cb) => pool.query(
      countQuery,
      (err, data) => {
        if (!err) {
          result.totalItem = parseInt(data.rows[0].total_item);
          result.totalPage = Math.ceil(result.totalItem / numPerPage);
          result.lastItem = (pageNum * numPerPage > result.totalItem) ?
            result.totalItem : (pageNum * numPerPage)
        }
        cb(err, result);
      })
  }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      result.error = err.message;
    }
    response.json(result.rows)
  })
});
```

Comment: Don't start with `async`/`await`. Learn about promises and how promisify your callback-taking functions (`pool.query`) first

Comment: Also, beware of SQL injections!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to keep the code similar to what you have above, but I noticed at the end that you're using a higher level `result` object to pass references around.

In the below code, I'm not using `async/await` since that's not entirely necessary for this example since the `pool.query` method takes a callback. Instead, I created `rows` and `count` functions that return Promises. Then I use those with `Promise.all` which will let both promises run in parallel and return the results as an array in the same order the promises are passed to `Promise.all`. See further down for an example using `async/await` when `pool.query` returns a promise instead.

```
router.post('/getDetail', (request, response, next) => {

  const id = request.body.id;
  const numPerPage = request.body.pSize;
  const pageNum = request.body.pIndex;

  let query = `select id,name,title,group_desc,unit_code from table1
              where id = '${id}'`;

  let countQuery = `select count(*) total_item from 
                   (select id,name,title,group_desc,unit_code from table1
                    where id = '${id}') a`;

  const result = {};
  Promise.all([
    rows(),
    count()
  ])
  .then(results => {
    // results is an array and the first item is `rows`
    response.json(results[0]);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle error
  });

  function rows() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.query(
        query,
        (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }

          result.dataRows = data.rows;
          result.numPerPage = numPerPage;
          result.pageNum = pageNum;
          result.totalPage = Math.ceil(result.totalItem / numPerPage);
          result.firstItem = (pageNum - 1) * numPerPage + 1;
          result.lastItem = (pageNum * numPerPage > result.totalItem) ?
            result.totalItem : (pageNum * numPerPage);
          resolve(result);
        });
    });
  }

  function count() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.query(
        countQuery,
        (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }
          result.totalItem = parseInt(data.rows[0].total_item);
          result.totalPage = Math.ceil(result.totalItem / numPerPage);
          result.lastItem = (pageNum * numPerPage > result.totalItem) ?
            result.totalItem : (pageNum * numPerPage);
          resolve(result);
        });
    });
  }
});
```

The next example shows using `async/await` assuming `pool.query` can return a Promise. I'm also making the assumption that the object references will still be maintained and is why I'm assigning `result.rows = results[0]` in the `try` part of the `try/catch`.

```
router.post('/getDetail', async(request, response, next) => {

  const id = request.body.id;
  const numPerPage = request.body.pSize;
  const pageNum = request.body.pIndex;

  let query = `select id,name,title,group_desc,unit_code from table1
              where id = '${id}'`;

  let countQuery = `select count(*) total_item from 
                   (select id,name,title,group_desc,unit_code from table1
                    where id = '${id}') a`;

  const result = {};
  try {
    const results = await Promise.all([rows(), count()]);
    // results is an array and the first item is `rows`
    result.rows = results[0];
  } catch (err) {
    result.error = err.message;
  }
  response.json(result.rows);

  async function rows() {
    const data = await pool.query(query);
    result.dataRows = data.rows;
    result.numPerPage = numPerPage;
    result.pageNum = pageNum;
    result.totalPage = Math.ceil(result.totalItem / numPerPage);
    result.firstItem = (pageNum - 1) * numPerPage + 1;
    result.lastItem = (pageNum * numPerPage > result.totalItem)
      ? result.totalItem
      : (pageNum * numPerPage);
    return result;
  }

  async function count() {
    const data = await pool.query(countQuery);
    result.totalItem = parseInt(data.rows[0].total_item);
    result.totalPage = Math.ceil(result.totalItem / numPerPage);
    result.lastItem = (pageNum * numPerPage > result.totalItem)
      ? result.totalItem
      : (pageNum * numPerPage);
    return result;
  }
});
```

I hope this helps you understand how you can do parallel processing with `async/await`. The only issue I see that may come up in your code is if the `rows` query returns before the `count` query since `totalItem` won't be set yet.

EDIT: personally, I think I would handle the logic like this with 1 query instead of 2 different queries:

```
router.post('/getDetail', async(request, response, next) => {
  const id = request.body.id;
  const numPerPage = request.body.pSize;
  const pageNum = request.body.pIndex;

  let query = `select id,name,title,group_desc,unit_code from table1
              where id = '${id}'`;

  const result = {};
  try {
    const data = await pool.query(query);
    result.dataRows = data.rows;
    result.totalItem = data.rows.length; // data might already have a property for this
    result.numPerPage = numPerPage;
    result.pageNum = pageNum;
    result.totalPage = Math.ceil(result.totalItem / numPerPage);
    result.firstItem = (pageNum - 1) * numPerPage + 1;
    result.lastItem = (pageNum * numPerPage > result.totalItem)
      ? result.totalItem
      : (pageNum * numPerPage);
  } catch (err) {
    result.error = err.message;
  }

  response.json(result);
});
```

EDIT 2: After more discussion in the comments, I think this version will work better. It doesn't use the main `result` object to provide references and moves the "count" based properties to the `count` function to allow for parallel execution:

```
router.post('/getDetail', async(request, response, next) => {

  const id = request.body.id;
  const numPerPage = request.body.pSize;
  const pageNum = request.body.pIndex;

  let query = `select id,name,title,group_desc,unit_code from table1
              where id = '${id}'`;

  let countQuery = `select count(*) total_item from 
                   (select id,name,title,group_desc,unit_code from table1
                    where id = '${id}') a`;

  let result = { numPerPage, pageNum };
  try {
    const results = await Promise.all([rows(), count()]);
    // this will combine the properties from both results onto the `result` object
    result = Object.assign({}, result, ...results);
  } catch (err) {
    result.error = err.message;
  }
  response.json(result);

  async function rows() {
    const data = await pool.query(query);
    return { dataRows: data.rows };
  }

  async function count() {
    const data = await pool.query(countQuery);
    // redefining result here to be only used in this scope
    const result = {};
    result.totalItem = parseInt(data.rows[0].total_item);
    result.totalPage = Math.ceil(result.totalItem / numPerPage);
    result.firstItem = (pageNum - 1) * numPerPage + 1;
    result.lastItem = (pageNum * numPerPage > result.totalItem)
      ? result.totalItem
      : (pageNum * numPerPage);
    return result;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @doowb. I tried the async method. I did a console.log(result.rows) and I get data. But in the UI, all I get is an empty object.

Comment: CAn you guide me to fix the async/await issue?

Comment: you might not have an issue if your data is coming back fine. It's hard for me to tell, but the answer I gave is how you would use `async/await` and promises together instead of the callbacks. (btw... i didn't see your comments earlier because I didn't get notifications from SO until just now)

Comment: Yeah, the data comes back fine. I am able to log it and see the data. But in the UI, all I can see is an empty object. As you said, rows query might get returned before counts query and that might be the thing.

Comment: I added a 3rd code block with how I would personally handle that query. It might show your data now.

Comment: The reason why I have two queries is because I have a limit clause in the main query and I need the counts query to get me the total count for pagination. In this case, since I only fetch 5 at a time, it wouldnt work I guess.

Comment: oh, there isn't a limit clause in the one in the example code so I missed that part. In that case, if you want to run them in parallel, move all of the `totalItem` based property calculations to the `count` function (like `firstItem` and `lastItem`) and remove them from the `rows` function. The will keep the resulting data calcuations independent and allow it to run in parallel.

Comment: Tried that too. Looks like result is sent in the response even before the data from the database is returned and is an empty object. Is there a specific place I should put my response.json?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177693/discussion-between-a2441918-and-doowb).